# How to change datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0) to 1/1/2012 in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to search date `1/1/2012` in a data frame using a `for` loop and I get the corresponding rates. However my date is in a format of `datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0)`. So automatically the condition to match the date is failing.

```
Start Date  End Date    RPI Amount
1/1/1987    31/01/1987  100.0
2/1/1987    28/02/1987  100.4
3/1/1987    31/03/1987  100.6
4/1/1987    30/04/1987  101.8
5/1/1987    31/05/1987  101.9
6/1/1987    30/06/1987  101.9
7/1/1987    31/07/1987  101.8
8/1/1987    31/08/1987  102.1
9/1/1987    30/09/1987  102.4
10/1/1987   31/10/1987  102.9
11/1/1987   30/11/1987  103.4
12/1/1987   31/12/1987  103.3
1/1/1988    31/01/1988  103.3
```

I have used a `for` loop to iterate over data frame and then tried to match the date with data frame date. However as the format not matches I am getting result as "NA"

```
rpi_index_start_date=datetime.strptime(f"{temp_month}/1/{temp_year}","%m/%d/%Y")

temp_year2=rpi_index_start_date.year+1
temp_month2=temp_month
temp_day2=temp_day

#RPI index end date calculation
rpi_index_end_date=datetime.strptime(f"{temp_month2}/{temp_day2}/{temp_year2}","%m/%d/%Y")

for i,row in rpi_rates_df.iterrows():
    if rpi_index_start_date==rpi_rates_df.loc[i,"Start Date"]:
        index_start_rpi=rpi_rates_df.loc[i,"RPI Amount"]
    else:
        index_start_rpi="NA"
```

I have to convert `datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0)` in `1/1/2012` format to search in the dataframe.

I expect the output 238 corresponding to 1/1/2012, but the actual output is NA.

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves any problems or not, but you've swapped your days/months in the `End Date` column

Comment: Your end date also has the month left-padded with zeroes. "01" etc

Comment: I am searching start date in the data frame not the end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the leading zeros on the month and day

**For those that use windows:**

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0).strftime("#%m/#%d/%Y")
```

**For those that do not use windows:**

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0).strftime("-%m/-%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [strftime](http://strftime.org):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

output:

```
01-01-2012'
```

Comment: rpi_index_start_date stores datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0) which need to be converted to 1/1/2012.